# More data than expected

Tags: python, validation, exception

I have file that contains set data of temperatures, of 12 months:

[image]

and I have this code:

```
if n <= 0: #validate the size 
     raise ValueError("Invalid data set size value.")
for i in range(n):
     line = infile.readline()  #read a data set 
if line != "":
     raise RuntimeError("more data sets than expected") #check if there is more lines than expected
```

when I run the program the output is

> Error:more data sets than expected

Comment: What's `n` ? Your question isn't clear at all : indeed, it's quite normal that it raises the last exception.

Comment: More importantly, fix your indentation please.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please don't paste images of your data, where it is text, copy and paste the characters so that we can do that to reproduce your problem.

Comment: it should not raise this exception cause the size of data is equal to the number of lines

Comment: how can it be more data sets than expected if the data expected = 12 ?

Comment: n = 12 size of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 12 lines of data, which you read line-by-line 12 times. After the 12th read, `line` contains the last line of data, and doesn't get cleared. This is why   `line != ""` evaluates to true, and the error is thrown. Perhaps you should readline one more time

```
for i in range(n):
    line = infile.readline()  #read a data set 
if infile.readline() != "":
    raise RuntimeError("more data sets than expected") #check if there is more lines than expected
```

Note that there are better ways to deal with this:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
if len(lines) > n:
    raise RuntimeError("more data sets than expected") #check if there is more lines than expected
```